# I am trying enable vulkan validation layer on windows. but I get the following errors:

Tags: c, windows, vulkan

FILE: exit_codes.h

```
#pragma once
// EXIT CODES
/* #define EXIT_SUCCESS 0 */
/* #define EXIT_FAILURE 1 */
#define SDL_INIT_VIDEO_FAILED 2
#define SDL_WINDOW_CREATE_FAILED 3
#define SDL_GET_SURFACE_FAILED 4
#define SDL_GET_DISPLAY_MODE_FAILED 5
#define VKINSTANCE_CREATION_FAILED 6
#define VKSURFACEKHR_CREATION_FAILED 7
#define MALLOC_FAILED 8
#define VULKAN_VALIDATION_LAYERS_FAILED 9
#define VULKAN_DEBUG_MESSENGER_FAILED 10
```

FILE: chk.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

#define chk(expr, str, err_code, ...) do {                                         \
    if(!(expr)) {                                                                  \
        fprintf(stderr,"At function %s in file %s:%d, chk failed: (%s). ",         \
               (__func__), (__FILE__), (__LINE__), (#expr));                       \
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s\n", (str));                                      \
        { __VA_ARGS__; }                                                           \
        exit(err_code);                                                            \
    }                                                                              \
} while(/*CONSTCOND*/0)
```

FILE: main.c

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#define DEBUG_VULKAN
#define PRINT_ALL_VALID_LAYERS
/* SDL + Vulkan */
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_vulkan.h>

/* STD LIB */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* Macros */
#include "macros/chk.h"
#include "macros/exit_codes.h"

#define WINDOW_NAME "Text Editor"

void sdl_initialize(SDL_Window** window) {
    
    SDL_SetMainReady();
    chk(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0, SDL_GetError(), SDL_INIT_VIDEO_FAILED);
    SDL_DisplayMode current_display_mode;
    chk(SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &current_display_mode) == 0, SDL_GetError(), SDL_GET_DISPLAY_MODE_FAILED);
    SDL_WindowFlags win_flags = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN;
    *window = SDL_CreateWindow(WINDOW_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, current_display_mode.w, current_display_mode.h, win_flags);
    chk(*window, SDL_GetError(), SDL_WINDOW_CREATE_FAILED, SDL_Quit());

}

#ifdef DEBUG_VULKAN                                                                     

bool check_validation_layer_support(const char** layer, uint32_t len) {

    uint32_t layer_count = 0, match_count = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layer_count, NULL);
    VkLayerProperties *available_layers = malloc(sizeof(VkLayerProperties) * layer_count);
    if (!available_layers) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc Failed for available_layers");
        return false;
    }

    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layer_count, available_layers);

#ifdef PRINT_ALL_VALID_LAYERS
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < layer_count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", available_layers[i].layerName);
    }
#endif

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < layer_count; j++) {
            if (strcmp(layer[i], available_layers[j].layerName) == 0) {
                match_count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    free(available_layers);
    return match_count == len;
}

static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity, VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType, 
                                                    const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT* pCallbackData, void* pUserData) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Validation Layer: %s\n", pCallbackData->pMessage);
    return VK_FALSE;
}

VkResult CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT* pCreateInfo,
                                      const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* pDebugMessenger) {
    
    PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT func = (PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func != NULL) {
        return func(instance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pDebugMessenger);
    }
    else {
        return VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
}

void DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator) {
    PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT func = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func != NULL) {
        func(instance, debugMessenger, pAllocator);
    }
}

#endif

void vulkan_create_instance(VkInstance* instance, SDL_Window** window) {
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT* pdebugCreateInfo;
#ifdef DEBUG_VULKAN
    const char* validation_layers[] = { "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" };
    const uint32_t layer_len = 1;
    chk(check_validation_layer_support(validation_layers, layer_len), "Validation layer support not available", VULKAN_VALIDATION_LAYERS_FAILED, SDL_DestroyWindow(*window), SDL_Quit());
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT debugCreateInfo = {0};
    pdebugCreateInfo = &debugCreateInfo;
    debugCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSENGER_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
    debugCreateInfo.messageSeverity = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT;
    debugCreateInfo.messageType = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_GENERAL_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_VALIDATION_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_BIT_EXT;
    debugCreateInfo.pfnUserCallback = debugCallback;
#else
    const char* validation_layers[] = NULL;
    const uint32_t layer_len = 0;
    pdebugCreateInfo = NULL;
#endif

    VkApplicationInfo app_info = { 0 };
    app_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    app_info.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_3;
    app_info.pApplicationName = "Text Editor";
    app_info.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_API_VERSION(1, 0, 0, 0);
    app_info.pEngineName = "Text Editor Engine";
    app_info.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_API_VERSION(1, 0, 0, 0);

    uint32_t count = 0;
    SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(*window, &count, NULL);
    const char** extensions = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
    chk(extensions, "Malloc failed for extensions", MALLOC_FAILED, SDL_DestroyWindow(*window), SDL_Quit());
    SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(*window, &count, extensions);

     
    VkInstanceCreateInfo instance_info = { 0 };
    instance_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instance_info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    instance_info.enabledLayerCount = layer_len;
    instance_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = validation_layers;
    instance_info.enabledExtensionCount = count;
    instance_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions;
    instance_info.pNext = pdebugCreateInfo;
    chk(vkCreateInstance(&instance_info, NULL, instance) == VK_SUCCESS,
        "Failed to create Vulkan instance",
        VKINSTANCE_CREATION_FAILED,
        free(extensions),
        SDL_DestroyWindow(*window),
        SDL_Quit()
    );

#ifdef DEBUG_VULKAN
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger;
    chk(CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(*instance, &debugCreateInfo, NULL, &debugMessenger) == VK_SUCCESS, "Failed to set up debug messenger!", VULKAN_DEBUG_MESSENGER_FAILED, 
        free(extensions), vkDestroyInstance(*instance, NULL), SDL_DestroyWindow(*window), SDL_Quit());
#endif

    free(extensions);
}

void app_loop() {

    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            switch (e.type) {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q && (SDL_GetModState() & KMOD_CTRL)) {
                    quit = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}


int main(int argc, char** agrv) {
    
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    sdl_initialize(&window);

    VkInstance instance = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    vulkan_create_instance(&instance, &window);

    VkSurfaceKHR surface = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    chk(SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface(window, instance, &surface) != SDL_FALSE,
        SDL_GetError(),
        VKSURFACEKHR_CREATION_FAILED,
        vkDestroyInstance(instance, NULL);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
    );


    // Application loop
    app_loop();
    

    vkDestroySurfaceKHR(instance, surface, NULL);
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, NULL);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
VK_LAYER_NV_optimus
VK_LAYER_OW_OVERLAY
VK_LAYER_OW_OBS_HOOK
VK_LAYER_OW_OVERLAY
VK_LAYER_OW_OBS_HOOK
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_gfxreconstruct
VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_synchronization2
VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_screenshot
VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_profiles
VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_shader_object
Validation Layer: windows_get_device_registry_files: GUID for 4 is not SoftwareComponent skipping
Validation Layer: Searching for ICD drivers named .\nvoglv64.dll
Validation Layer: loader_get_json: Failed to open JSON file C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_1d9a63fa126c4a34\igvk64.json
Validation Layer: Layer VK_LAYER_OW_OVERLAY uses API version 1.2 which is older than the application specified API version of 1.3. May cause issues.
Validation Layer: Layer VK_LAYER_OW_OBS_HOOK uses API version 1.2 which is older than the application specified API version of 1.3. May cause issues.
Validation Layer: Loading layer library C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.268.0\Bin\.\VkLayer_khronos_validation.dll
Validation Layer: Loading layer library C:\Program Files (x86)\Overwolf\0.236.0.11\.\ow-graphics-vulkan.dll
Validation Layer: Loading layer library C:\Program Files (x86)\Overwolf\0.236.0.11\.\owclient.dll
Validation Layer: Loading layer library C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvacig.inf_amd64_6178dee678589680\.\nvoglv64.dll
At function vulkan_create_instance in file main.c:146, chk failed: (CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(*instance, &debugCreateInfo, NULL, &debugMessenger) == VK_SUCCESS). Error: Failed to set up debug messenger!
Validation Layer: Unloading layer library C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvacig.inf_amd64_6178dee678589680\.\nvoglv64.dll
Validation Layer: Unloading layer library C:\Program Files (x86)\Overwolf\0.236.0.11\.\owclient.dll
Validation Layer: Unloading layer library C:\Program Files (x86)\Overwolf\0.236.0.11\.\ow-graphics-vulkan.dll
Validation Layer: Unloading layer library C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.268.0\Bin\.\VkLayer_khronos_validation.dll
```

First of all I am not trying load Overwolf just the VkLayer_khronos_validation as far as my understanding. I do not understand why Overwolf validation layers are being loaded. I have the overwolf application on my computer but no in my code. Secondly The json loader fails and the debug messenger fails. If anyone can quickly spot the issue and let me know it would be really helpful. I am writing this code on Windows OS if that is relevant.

to compile the code I use the following batch command:

```
@echo off
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" && cd C:\Users\shanto\source\text_editor && cl main.c SDL2.lib SDL2Main.lib vulkan-1.lib"
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't appear to be requesting the `VK_EXT_debug_utils` extension when creating the VkInstance.

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my issue of program crashing but still the problem of
loading implicit layers found in windows registry for other applications I use. I do not want them to load in my vulkan application. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can use [`VK_LOADER_LAYERS_DISABLE`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/main/docs/LoaderInterfaceArchitecture.md#table-of-debug-environment-variables) to disable specific or all implicit layers.